# Create a Transaction to Rollback DB Operations Around this `Manager` Structure

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have created a "manager" object around an SQLAlchemy database engine/connection/session:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self, connection: str = 'sqlite://'):
        self.engine = create_engine(connection, echo=True)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = scoped_session(self.sessionmaker)

    def do_db_stuff(self):
        self.session.query(Whatever).all()

    def ensure_thing(self):
        thing = Thing()
        self.session.add(thing)
        self.session.commit()
```

I would like to create two py.test fixtures: one to instantiate the manager and one to wrap and rollback transactions in tests that may call commit. [This is the pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites) I have attempted to follow, without success:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def manager():
    m = Manager()
    return m


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def manager_session(manager):
    connection = manager.session.connection()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    yield manager

    manager.session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
```

Unfortunately, objects created by the manager even when surrounded by the above stick around after the call to `transaction.rollback()`.

What is the proper way to wrap a transaction around an existing session like this?

EDIT:

Another, different attempt:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def manager_session(manager):
    connection = manager.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    manager.sessionmaker.configure(bind=connection)

    yield manager

    manager.session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
```

EDIT 2:

A third attempt that seems to work, with the caveat mentioned in [Ilja Everilä's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918055/600882) that threaded code would cause trouble.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def manager():
    return Manager()


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def manager_transaction(manager):
    connection = manager.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    manager.session_maker.configure(bind=connection)

    yield manager

    manager.session_maker.configure(bind=manager.engine)
    manager.session.remove()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: How did the 2nd attempt fail?

Comment: The failure came after the first test using the fixture completed and the second test began. I think (but am not sure) that the second test got the same session despite my having closed it. Switching to `session.remove` fixed this, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st attempt fails because the session is actually in control of the connection and its transaction. You can verify that from looking at the produced logging. The session begins an implicit transaction when you call `manager.session.connection()` and your explicit call to `begin()` after is a no operation that returns the ongoing transaction object. So when you commit in the manager methods, you commit for real, and the now stale transaction object does nothing when you rollback.

The 2nd attempt works for me *as is*, if using in-memory SQLite DB, but it would not work if your actual code is slightly different from what you've presented. You set the created connection as bind on the `self.sessionmaker`, not on a session in the already created [scoped session registry](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) `self.session`, and so if you have touched the session registry in any way before configuring the maker, you have actually created a session using the engine as bind in the current thread:

```
In [7]: m = Manager()

In [8]: m.session.bind
Out[8]: Engine(sqlite://)

In [9]: connection = m.engine.connect()

In [10]: transaction = connection.begin()
2017-08-28 14:24:02,584 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)

In [11]: m.sessionmaker.configure(bind=connection)

In [12]: m.session.bind
Out[12]: Engine(sqlite://)
```

So in addition to configuring the sessionmaker, you should make sure that a session has not been registered in the registry before. Also note that if you have code that uses threads, the registry will share the connection between them, and that's going to cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments. I did notice some warnings during my random walk towards a solution about configuring a sessionmaker with existing sessions. I'm not using threads in this code, but do you have any thoughts on how to get around that specific problem as well? Perhaps a custom sessionmaker might be in order...

Comment: Would it be better to do something like `...setup transaction; manager.session(bind=connection); yield manager; ...` and skip the configuration of the sessionmaker entirely?